# Build tflite c++ lib for android with ndk 25 > with bazel

Tags: android, c++, tensorflow, android-ndk, bazel

I'm building a huge project that requires ndk versions above 25 (I'm using 25.0.8775105 right now). And I would like to use TFLite on my project. Following the docs, to cross-compile it on my x86-64 machine to be suitable for arm64-v8a architectures the instructions goes as follows:

1. Get tensorflow source
2. Install bazel (I've tried both 6.0.0 and the 7.0.0-prebuild)
3. Run `./configure` and say `y` to `Would you like to interactively configure ./WORKSPACE for Android builds?`, then configure it.
4. Run `bazel build -c opt --config=android_arm64 //tensorflow/lite:libtensorflowlite.so`
5. Extract the .so file and get the header files than use like any other library.

When I run `./configure` and say yes to configuring `./WORKSPACE`, it wants me to provide an ndk directory. However, when I provide it (it being `/home/tb/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.0.8775105` on my system, very similar to what's recommended) I get hit with this: `WARNING: The NDK version in /home/tb/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.0.8775105 is 25, which is not supported by Bazel (officially supported versions: [19, 20, 21]). Please use another version. Compiling Android targets may result in confusing errors.`  followed by an error caused by this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tb/Desktop/tensorflow/tensorflow_src/./configure.py", line 1363, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/tb/Desktop/tensorflow/tensorflow_src/./configure.py", line 1336, in main
    create_android_ndk_rule(environ_cp)
  File "/home/tb/Desktop/tensorflow/tensorflow_src/./configure.py", line 653, in create_android_ndk_rule
    get_ndk_api_level(environ_cp, android_ndk_home_path))
  File "/home/tb/Desktop/tensorflow/tensorflow_src/./configure.py", line 747, in get_ndk_api_level
    api_levels = sorted(os.listdir(platforms))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/tb/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.0.8775105/platforms'
```

I've tried compiling it with `bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/lite:libtensorflowlite.so --fat_apk_cpu=arm64-v8a` which did in fact built the .so file, but when I try to build the code it says `C/C++: ld: error: undefined symbol: tflite::impl::Interpreter::Invoke()`, I did run my project on linux and it works fine, android uses a similar if not the same cmake file so I think the .so is broken.

What should I do? Does anyone have a link to, preferably official, pre-built tflite aarch64 / arm64-v8a .so file for c++?

Update: I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/59692) detailing everything I've tried up to now.

Comment: IDK how people manage to understand and use Bazel, it's more of a pain in the head than a build tool. In case you are facing too much issues, just raise one issue on their Github page (tensorflow's repo) and ask their developers to resolve that, let them break their heads :-P

Comment: @kiner_shah already did sadly... no response so far, you are right bazel is just making everything more complicated especially considering we have millon more tools and compilers out there...

Comment: Related: [Update the Android NDK to r25b LTS](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/57970), it looks like the pull request is still under review (and may be worth a look).

Comment: @MorrisonChang I really hope I'm not forced to wait for them to support a version released almost a year ago...

Comment: I would look at each file that got changed in the pull request and see if you are comfortable with merging the patch yourself for building. At worst you can comment on the issue ticket (or create a new one with references) with any problems you encounter.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I'm not sure I can patch the whole thing myself... I've opened an issue detailing everything I've tried and updated the question accordingly

Comment: @Turgut. You say that you were able to compile the project with NDK19, right? So, it should be no problem to mix NDK19 with your project using NDK 25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compile and use on my NDK 25 project, I've downloaded NDK 20, gave that as a path when I ran `./configure` and used ndk 20 path when I configured `WORKSPACE`. It compiled and using the include files from the same source I managed to run it. For anyone struggling you might want to switch to a different branch. I switched between branches a bit to finally find one that works (mainly the main branch or the vx.x or rx.x branches.).